# Are multiple comparators being returned?

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue

```
PriorityQueue<Student> pq = new PriorityQueue<(
    Comparator.comparing(Student::getCgpa).reversed()
    .thenComparing(Student::getFname)
    .thenComparing(Student::getToken)
    );
```

Are multiple comparators being returned? If so, how,
because this constructor only returns one.

Comment: Your second question just answers your first : how can it be ONE, because not multiple ones are returned

Answer (score 1):

"*Are multiple comparators being returned?*" - Yes, on a techical level. Each `Comparator` except for the last in the chain is used to create another `Comparator` (through the calls `reversed()` and `thenComparing()`). But only one is passed along as a parameter to the `PriorityQueue`:

```
Comparator.comparing(Student::getCgpa) // <- 1st comparator created & returned
    .reversed()                        // <- 2nd comparator created & returned
    .thenComparing(Student::getFname)  // <- 3nd comparator created & returned
    .thenComparing(Student::getToken)  // <- 4th comparator created, returned & passed along as argument
```

Comment: "*Returned? No*" It depends where you mean returned *from*. They are obviously *returned* from the methods which create them. The overall expression evaluates to a single Comparator reference. (I know that you know this, just think it's worth being precise)

Comment: @Michael reworded.

Answer (score 0):

- Are multiple comparators being returned?

  No
- if so how because this constructoronly returns one?

  From the [`thenComparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)) documentation, the given comparator is chained with the previous in one Comparator that can use several rules to sort values

---

From the code

```
default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<? super T> other) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(other);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> {
        int res = compare(c1, c2);
        return (res != 0) ? res : other.compare(c1, c2);
    };
}
```

The new comparator apply this

- use its own comparing test
- if value is `0` (equals element) then the parameter one is used to return its decision

---

So in fact, using multiple chaining results in recursivse tests

```
Comparator<Foo> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt(Foo::getA)
        .thenComparing(Foo::getB)
        .thenComparing(Foo::getC)
        .thenComparing(Foo::getD);

getA ->  1
     -> -1
     ->  0 -> getB ->  1
                   -> -1
                   ->  0 -> getC ->  1
                                 -> -1
                                 ->  0 -> getC ->  1
                                               -> -1
                                                ...
```